# Objects are not valid as a React child. If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead. Solution Please?

Tags: reactjs

Am new to react. I have trying to get the child elements of the layout component from the App.js file, but I keep getting Objects are not valid as a React child error. Below is my code from the App.js and Layout.js.

````
```
App.js code
```

import React from "react";
import Home from "./containers/Home";
import Login from "./containers/Login";
import Signup from "./containers/Signup";
import Activate from "./containers/Activate";
import ResetPassword from "./containers/ResetPassword";
import ResetPasswordConfirm from "./containers/ResetPasswordConfirm";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Layout from "./hocs/Layout.js";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "./store";

const App = () => (
<Provider store={store}>
<Router>
  <Layout>
    <Routes>
      <Route exact path="/" element={Home} />
      <Route exact path="/login" element={Login} />
      <Route exact path="/signup" element={Signup} />
      <Route
        exact
        path="/password/reset/confirm/:uid/:token"
        element={ResetPasswordConfirm}
      />
      <Route exact path="/reset-password" element={ResetPassword} />

      <Route exact path="/activate/:uid/:token" element={Activate} />
    </Routes>
      </Layout>
    </Router>
  </Provider>
);

export default App;

```
Code from Layout.js
```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import Navbar from "../components/Navbar";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { checkAuthenticated, load_user } from "../actions /auth";

const Layout = ({ checkAuthenticated, load_user, children }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    checkAuthenticated();
    load_user();
  }, [checkAuthenticated, load_user]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};

export default connect(null, { checkAuthenticated, load_user })(Layout);
````

How do I split my children or is there an alternative to this problem?

Comment: check the nested JSX that you're passing to this component

Comment: Please include all relevant code as text, not images.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Okay, i understand, Thanks